# Can I temporary disable file access rights?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

The problem: I want to run a proprietary app, but it has a bug. It creates a folder with a random name and permissions 000, then immediately tries to read it, says that it can not create a temp folder and quits. I can't fix the app.

The question: I need some kind of workaround. Some setting or trick that would allow the app to read its damn folder, without running the app as root.

Comment: That is not a bug to me but intended behavior. "proprietary app" says it all. Please include the name of the application in the question.  Without it an answer is going to be more difficult. "without running the app as root."  Ubuntu uses admin not root. `touch 1 && chmod 000 1 && sudo more 1` does not error out so you do not need root but the problem you then have: if it is a random name... you need to know the name upfront to do anything with it.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: 20.04 LTS Kubuntu